# How to shuffle values in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataset, shuffle

I have a dataset with a bunch of behavioral data collected on multiple days as following:

```
Day   Behav1     Behav2      Behav3 ... etc
1       4          10          7
1       etc        etc        etc
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
etc
```

I want to shuffle the day order (it goes from 1 to 10) without changing the rows. E.g. day 2 becomes d10, d10 becomes d1, etc. The issue here is that the data is not balanced, so observations on each day vary.
My idea is to ultimately create a function that can shuffle the days multiple times, and store each cycle as a separate dataset.
Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are after

```
df$Day <- sample(df$Day,length(df$Day))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also do

```
df$Day <- sample(df$Day)
```